# Reading from buffer to base64

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm storing images in a Postgres db in the following way:

```js
const image = Buffer.from("\\x" + Buffer.from(createEventDto.image, "base64").toString("hex"));
```

Now, I'm trying to read the image back from the db and decode it into a base64 string. I've tried simply this:

```js
const image = await db.get(); // here it's of type buffer
return image.toString("base64"); // want to return it as type string in base64
```

But the image comes back corrupted.

Comment: Why would you ever want to turn an image into a string. Are you embedding it in something. It's very inefficient. If `image.toString('base64')` corrupts I would guess something is going wrong in the first step where you're doing 3 conversions.

Comment: Why tack on `"\\x"`? Also `Buffer.from(createEventDto.image, "base64")` assumes `createEventDto.image` is base64 encoded to begin with... are you sure it is? Also I feel like `image.toString("base64")` should be `Buffer.from(image, "hex").toString("base64")` so that it knows `image` is hex encoded.

Comment: I'm trying to store images in base64 format in a db. I tried storing the base64 encoded versions of the images and reading them back, but I don't get the full picture back as some parts of it get corrupted for some reason.

Comment: Why do you store images as base64 strings? Why not as blob? For debugging, I would remove the database from the equation and test encoding and decoding step by step.